# How to list users in WebProtege 4.0?

Tags: ontology, protege, protege4

I'm running a server with WebProtege 4.0.0 from the docker images as described on the WebProtege github page.

Now I want to access a list of all users, how can I actually do that?

The best thing I've found so far is trying to share a project, type in all the letters individually and write down the names that show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is the best way, but I connected to the database and extracted the users that way.

```
docker exec -it webprotege_wpmongo_1 bash     # connect to docker containers shell.
mongo                                         # connect to mongodb shell
use webprotege                                # connect to specific database
db.Users.find().toArray()                     # find and show all users.
```